# Weak convergence of a nonlinear sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\left( {{u^n},{u_t}^n,{u_{tt}}^n} \right)$ be a bounded sequences $${\left[ {{L^2}(0,T;H_0^2(0,1))} \right]^2} \times {L^2}(0,T;H_0^1(0,1))$$, then there exists a sebsequences that will be noted $\left( {{u^n},{u_t}^n,{u_{tt}}^n} \right)$ such that $$\left( {{u^n},{u_t}^n,{u_{tt}}^n} \right) \to \left( {u,{u_t},{u_{tt}}} \right)$$ weakly star in $${\left[ {{L^2}(0,T;H_0^2(0,1))} \right]^2} \times {L^2}(0,T;H_0^1(0,1))$$.
Let ${\left( {{u_x^n}} \right)^2}$ be a bounded sequence in ${{L^2}(0,T;{L^2}(0,1))}$, how can I prove that  $${\left( {u_x^n} \right)^2} \to {u_x}^2$$ in  $${{L^2}(0,T;{L^2}(0,1))}$$ ?

Comment: No. Your first assertion means $u_{xx} \in L^2$ ($x$ denotes the spatial variable), and the second one $u_{tt} \in L^2$. You want to conclude $u_{ttxx} \in L^2$.

Comment: thank you sir for the answer, I have added some clarification above, the problem is clear now, I need some help.

Comment: Your question has two parts (1) listing some facts, (2) a question with no seemingly connection to (1) ?

Comment: I tried to explain the probem, that's all.